# Livewire 3 does not display variable value received by parameter and mount()

Tags: laravel, livewire-3

I have a CausasComponent component from where I call the ManagerComponent component. Both are full page. I pass it a Causa $causa model as a parameter. I get it in managerComponent with mount() but then I can't deploy it to the view. It doesn't show anything.

The call:

```
<td class="td-actions text-right" style="width: 10%;">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm d-inline" 
        href="{{ route('manager',  $causa) }}" 
        title="Gestionar causa">
        <i class="bi bi-gear"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

route:

```
Route::get('/manager/{causa}', ManagerComponent::class)->name('manager');
```

la rececpción en ManagerComponent

```
class ManagerComponent extends Component
{
    
    public $title = 'Causas';
    public Causa $causa;
    
    public function mount(Causa $causa)
    {
        $this->causa = $causa;
        
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.causas.manager-component')
            ->layout('livewire.causas.layouts.manager');
    }
}
```

The view

```
<div>
    {{$title }}  {{ $causa->name }}  
</div>
```

If I put a dd($causa) in mount() I can see the value of $causa that actually arrived. But it does not display it in the view. It does NOT throw an error. It just doesn't show anything.